# Material UI Switch does not update immediately in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a row component that contains all information about a project and a switch that shows the active status of the project (T or F).

```
  render() {
    const dateDisplay = moment(this.props.createdAt).format('MMM YYYY');
    return (
      <tr
        className="experiment-list__row"
        onMouseOver={() => this.props.onRowHovered(this.props.rowItems.id)}
      >
        <td>{this.props.rowItems.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.rowItems.owner}</td>
        <td>{dateDisplay}</td>
        <td className="experiment-list--col__switch">
          <Switch 
            color="primary" 
            checked={this.props.rowItems.status}
            onChange={()=>{this.handleSubmit(this.props.rowItems.id, this.props.rowItems.status)}}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
```

It looks like this. When I click the switch it is supposed to toggle and change the status based on the current status. The `handleSubmit` does it for me.

```
  handleSubmit(rowID: any, rowStatus: any) {

    console.log(rowID, rowStatus)
    makeMutation(UpdateExperimentQuery, {
      update: {
        id: rowID,
        data: {
          status: !rowStatus
        },
      },
    })
      .then(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

It updates the data correctly.

However, it does not get updated immediately even though the `checked` attribute of the switch represents the `status` of the row.

When I refresh it, it changes, but I want it to show it immediately since that's the point of using react.

Please help

**EDIT**

- Displays the Info

  ```
  <div className="experiments-list-container">

      <List
        onRowHovered={this.getExperimentID}
        rowItems={this.state.experimentData}
      />

  </div>
  ```
- This is a different Component `ListRow`

  ```
  const List = props => {
    return (
      <table className="experiment-list">
        <tbody>
          <ListHeader />
          {props.rowItems.map((data, i) => (
            <ListRow key={i} rowItems={data} onRowHovered={props.onRowHovered} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };
  ```

  The render of `ListRow`

  ```
  export class ListRow extends Component<ListRowProps, ListRowState> {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        experimentData: [],
        status: props.status //unused right now
      };

      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    // also not used now
    componentWillUpdate() {
      if (this.state.status !== this.props.status) {
        this.setState({
          status: this.props.status,
        });
      }
    }

    handleSubmit(rowID: any, rowStatus: any) {

      console.log(rowID, rowStatus)
      makeMutation(UpdateExperimentQuery, {
        update: {
          id: rowID,
          data: {
            status: !rowStatus
          },
        },
      })
        .then(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
      const dateDisplay = moment(this.props.createdAt).format('MMM YYYY');
      return (
        <tr
          className="experiment-list__row"
          onMouseOver={() => this.props.onRowHovered(this.props.rowItems.id)}
        >
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.name}</td>
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.owner}</td>
          <td>{dateDisplay}</td>
          <td className="experiment-list--col__switch">
            <Switch 
              color="primary" 
              checked={this.props.rowItems.status}
              onChange={()=>{this.handleSubmit(this.props.rowItems.id, this.props.rowItems.status)}}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }
  ```

**EDIT**

```
  changeStatus(rowID, rowStatus) {
    // close if the selected employee is clicked

    console.log(rowID, rowStatus)

     makeMutation(UpdateExperimentQuery, {
        update: {
          id: rowID,
          data: {
            status: !rowStatus
          },
        },
      })
      .then(responseData => {

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.componentWillMount();
        },1000);

        console.log('responseData', responseData)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

this updates the data and gets called in the `List` component.

```
  componentWillMount() {

    let filteredData = []

    //this.props.fetchExperiments();
    makeQuery(ExperimentsListQuery)
      .then(responseData => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          experimentData: responseData.Experiments,
        }));

        for(var i = 0; i < this.state.experimentData.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.state.experimentData[i])
          if(this.state.experimentData[i].status === this.state.viewActive) {
            filteredData.push(this.state.experimentData[i])
          }
        }

        this.setState({
          filteredExpData: filteredData
        })

      })

      .catch(err => {
        //actions.setSubmitting(false);
        console.log(err);
      });

  }
```

this fetches/filters the data

Comment: What does that `makeMutation` function do? I think you're gonna need to show more code, like where the status is actually being stored.

Comment: makeMutation is just a graphql query that updates the data. I realized that the toggle doesn't work immediately because it uses a prop instead of states. Is there a way to pass in a state for each row and update them?

Comment: It should still work with a prop, the problem seems to be Apollo using a cached value instead of a fetched one. Setting the query option `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'` might help here. I'm assuming that the props you're using are coming from Apollo as well.

Comment: I'm using graphql without using Apollo. Which part of the code shall I provide?

Comment: How are you passing the `rowItems` prop to your component? After you do the graphql query, where exactly is the update supposed to be reflected locally?

Comment: Please check my edit! Thanks.

Comment: So the actual data the needs to be updated is in that top state, inside `experimentData`, and that never gets updated? There must be some place where you're updating `experimentData` on refresh, right?

Comment: I think so. What do I have to fix?

Comment: What I mean is, I think there's still something you're not including here. Where is the place in the code where the `experimentData` state is altered?

Comment: i added another edit